# Usage of "getting" in causative sentences

Tags: causatives, causative-get

I'm trying to make a causative sentences with "getting", but I can not. Are these sentences causative or not? Can you make a causative sentence with "getting"?

> What could be the result of getting trees removed?

and

> What's happened after getting your exam checked?

Comment: A little research might be in order: Causative Verbs In English: **Let, Make, Have, Get, Help** https://www.espressoenglish.net/causative-verbs-in-english-let-make-have-get-help/ get + thing or person + verb, get the grass cut, get my hair cut. Yours are ok.

Comment: It may be more acceptable in AmE (I dunno), but in BrE, *getting trees removed* is a bit "downmarket". We'd usually say *What could be the result of **having** trees removed?* for the first example here. I can't explain exactly why, but ***getting*** sounds "better" than ***having*** in the second example. But I don't like the overall construction anyway, since the relevant "subject" noun is missing. I'd bin the "contracted perfect" form there anyway, so I'd ask something like *What happened after **you got / you had** your exam checked?* (where I don't mind ***got*** so much).